# Change div/span content by url addition?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I dont find a solution, so maybe its not possible with jquery?

My plan:
I have some divs like this:

```
<div>
  <span class="en">Hello</span>
  <span class="de">Hallo</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="en">Whats up?</span>
  <span class="de">Wie geht´s?</span>
</div>
```

aso.

So, if my url is just www.domain.com/..., only the "en"-content should be shown. If the url is www.domain.com/de/..., only the "de"-content should be shown. Is this possible with jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var url = window.location.href;  //Get URL

if (url.includes("/de/")) {    //If URL Contains /de/
  $('.en').hide();
} else {
  $('.de').hide();
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you don't want to use `includes` due to browser support (as [FlatLander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1262168/flatlander) points out in his answer, `includes` is ES6), then you can use `indexOf`:

```
var url = window.location.href;  //Get URL

if (url.indexOf("/de/") !== -1) {    //If URL Contains /de/
  $('.en').hide();
} else {
  $('.de').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Cross browser support**

`includes` is not available in all browser so try indexOf

```
var url = window.location.href;    

if (url.indexOf("/de/") !== -1) {    //If URL Contains /de/
  $('.en').hide();
} else {
  $('.de').hide();
}
```

`includes` is an es6 feature https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I'd make sure to include the slashes in your `indexOf`. Using this code, a page called `destination.html` would throw `true` because it contains `de`.

Comment: sorry missed that :P